# try to create new variable using loop in R,but failed

Tags: r

I am a new user to R.I have already imported all data from all my txt file using the code down below,but i want to create a new variable when importing data,the variable is called case.The value of case for the first row is 1 and for the rest is 0.

And when i try to run the code,the console did not say anytime wrong ,the data has been imported, but the new variable wasn't created.I don't know why.

```
for(i in Filenames){
  perpos <- which(strsplit(i, "")[[1]]==".")
  data=assign(
    gsub(" ","",substr(i, 1, perpos-1)),
    read.table(paste(filepath,i,sep=""),fill=TRUE,header=TRUE,quote ="",row.names = NULL,sep="\t")
  )
  strsplit(i, "")
  filename  = strsplit(as.character(i),"\\.txt")
  data$case = ifelse(data$NAME=="filename",1,0)
}
```

Comment: Don't use `data = assign(...)`; the purpose of `assign` is not its return value. Your `strsplit(i,"")` in contrast does need to be assigned somewhere.

Comment: Are you trying to match `data$NAME` with the variable `filename` above it or the literal string `"filename"`.

Comment: not the literal string "filename",data$NAME is a list of names,the first one is case,others are controls.And i forget to delete`strsplit(i,"")`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys! I used @joosts's code and made some ajustment. The code down below works just fine.

```
fn <- paste(filepath,Filenames,sep="")
mylist <- lapply(fn, read.table,fill = TRUE, header = TRUE, quote = "",row.names = NULL, sep = "\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
for(i in 1:length(Filenames)){
mylist[[i]]<- cbind(mylist[[i]], case = 0)
if(nrow(mylist[[i]])>0) {
mylist[[i]]$case[1] <- 1
}
mylist[[i]]<- cbind(mylist[[i]], ID = i)
}
do.call(rbind, mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to read in multiple text files, with each file containing the same columns (in the same order). In order to combine multiple `dataframe`s (the things that result from calling `read.data()`), you should call the function `rbind()`.
And I assume your code to get a filename without the extension is slightly overcomplex...

```
for(file in filenames) {
 sanitized_filename <- gsub(" ", "", strsplit(file, "\\.")[[1]][1])
 file.frame <- read.table(paste(filepath, file, sep=""), fill = TRUE, header = TRUE, quote = "", row.names = NULL, sep = "\t")
 file.frame <- cbind(file.frame, name = I(sanitized_filename), case = 0)
 if(nrow(file.frame)>0) {
   file.frame$case[1] <- 1
 }
 data <- ifelse(exists("data"), rbind(data, file.frame), file.frame)
}
```

Comment: joosts,thanks a lot! But when i try to run the code ,it says`Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'`,why?

Comment: Not really sure... if you could show me some of data files I could improve the code above... (missing any input I just had to make this one up without testing).

Comment: i'm sorry i can't show you my file,it's data collected from patients. what do you mean by` ifelse(exists("data"), rbind(data, file.frame), file.frame)
}`,data wasn't defined before

Comment: Exactly if data didnt exist it is created from the new data frame else it is merged with the existing fast using rbind... I probably will be able to help you with two fake data files as well.

Comment: how can i send you the file? btw,i can't read in all the files using your code,only the first one,and the amount of variables became strange....

Comment: `NAME     Team      Age   FB%   FBv 
A.J. ahuiah Cardinals 28 
Bob hsaudi Dodgers 28 NA  
fdasf Thdewdew Padres 28 66.50%  
ddc vfvdss Giants 28 60.90%  
fdaff vfsvvfd Padres 28 50.80% ` @joosts, i wish i can upload a picture of the fake file,it will be more convenient...

Comment: `NAME Team Age FB% FBv 
Cody Rsdas Cardinals 35 
dnwejdew Yankees 35 44.10%
grttgerg Nationals 35 
gtergrtger Indians 35 83.00% 
Jigtem Megtgt Marlins 35 62.50% 
juyjuyjm Nationals 35 
gtrgtrgrg Mets 35 67.50% 
ytjuyjuyj Reds 35 67.20% 
nhfgngfngh - - - 35 64.10% 
frefreferr Phillies35 93.5%`

Comment: Thans I LL have a look at it in a few hours

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I have figured it out@joosts. I posted my answer down below.

Comment: Great you beat me to the solution ;-)